# PHPMyAdmin error after updating EasyPHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I recently updated a version of my windows based Apache server (I'm using EasyPHP) and I'm having issues with PHP MyAdmin.  With the old version(13.1 VC9), I'm able to connect to the MyAdmin page, no problem.  However, I am not able to connect using the new version(14.1 VC9).  The error I get with the new version is:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.4.24
```

What do I need to do to be able to re-access PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Try logging out phpMyAdmin, clear cookies and login again?

Comment: Most probably you lost alias for phpmyadmin. Check if there is phpmyadmin.conf in easyphp's alias directory

Comment: MarkS:  If I have lost alias and the conf file is in the alias directory, what do I need to do?  I'm not at home right now so I can't check, but will in a couple hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simple open `http://127.0.0.1/home/`

And here you have sections modules. You should have here at least one phpmyadmin and when you click it, it will open phpMyAdmin.

If you want to use alias - for example you want to load phpmyadmin using `http://phpmyadmin` you will have to create it.

So go again to `http://127.0.0.1/home/` and check if below phpmyadmin modules you have Virtual Hosts Manager 1.4 . If not, close easyphp , go to `http://www.easyphp.org/modules.php`, download and install Virtual Hosts Manager (choose the one for 14.1 VC9).

After you start again easyphp you should have at `http://127.0.0.1/home/` your Virtual Hosts Manager 1.4 . Now simple click on "Add virtual host", as a name you can for example insert **phpmyadmin** and in path directory you should insert the whole system path to directory where you have phpmyadmin. For example mine is **D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\modules\phpmyadmin420x140509165737**. Save it and now you will be able to open phpmyadmin using your alias as for example `http://phpmyadmin`

Comment: That's what I was doing, but it still wasn't working.  So, I just uninstalled everything and reinstalled it.  Thanks for helping though.